# How to scale Google maps

Tags: google-maps

The following works.  It tracks me as I walk around the office:

```
(function() {
    var Variables = {}
    Variables.Counter = 0

    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    function initialize() {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(centerTheMap);
    }
    function centerTheMap(arg) {
        $('.msg').text('latitude 1: ' + arg.coords.latitude + ', longitude: ' + arg.coords.longitude)
        var mapOptions = {
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(arg.coords.latitude, arg.coords.longitude)
            ,zoom: 18
        };
        Variables.myMap = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(arg.coords.latitude, arg.coords.longitude);
        Variables.myMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
             position: myLatlng,
             map: Variables.myMap
        });
        navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(DisplayMyNewLocation);
    }
    function DisplayMyNewLocation(arg) {
        Variables.Counter += 1
        $('.msg').text('latitude ' + Variables.Counter + ': ' + arg.coords.latitude + ', longitude: ' + arg.coords.longitude)
        Variables.myMarker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(arg.coords.latitude, arg.coords.longitude))
    }

})()
```

Now, here's my question:

I'd like for it to scale 1:3000 so that if I walk a mile, it's tracking me walking across the continental United States.

So it should start at my current position, but then as I walk it should update on a scale of 1:3000.